# How to change an @State var with a UIButton in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, xcode11

I tried to use a button to change the value of this @State variable using the code below.
Even if it doesn't involve using a button, how would I change an @State var?(or any var type for SwiftUI)

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {

    @State var x = 0

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: //x = 1
) {
            Text("Button")
        }
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is syntax error in your code. you missed to write closure for `Button`

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State var x = 0
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
           self.x = 1
        }) {
           Text("Button")
        }
    }
}
```